# Sencha Touch Scrolling Sluggish on IE10/WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

So I've just gotten my app to work on IE10/WP8 ([demo here](http://www.bodbot.com/MobileApp/package2/index.html)), and one thing I've noticed is that both scrolling and transitioning between carousel cards are reasonably sluggish on Windows Phone. Specifically, it takes like half a second for the screen to catch up to my finger. I'd say it's at about 80% of the responsiveness than I get from Android and iPhone, which both have pretty much perfect responsiveness. For reference, here are the devices I'm testing with:

- iPhone 4
- Android Kyocera Rise
- WP8 Nokia Lumia 920
- Desktop PC (Windows 8)

So among the phones, my Windows Phone is easily the most powerful, so it likely isn't just a hardware consideration. I've found this sluggishness in fastbook (http://fb.html5isready.com) as well. However, the sluggishness on either app does not exist on my Windows 8 PC.

Is there a particular consideration that needs to be taken with this part of performance in WP8? I've done quite a lot of work optimizing overall performance on the app (destroying/recycling all unused DOM elements, event delegation, etc) and the rest of the app runs quite well. So I'm not sure where I should go from here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

How are you serving those large images? Have you tried using sencha.io to serve them? You can also use the yahoo tool smush.it to crush images further without loss of quality.

Another question: are you using CSS shadows and effects? These can have a noticeable performance hit sometimes...

Also the custom font, how are you implementing that? Google fonts work well, or are you implementing it another way?

:-)

Comment: On the large images: I get a performance hit even when it's a packaged hybrid app (Sencha+PhoneGap). On CSS shadows and Effects: For IE10/WP8, I'm not using any gradients, and just a couple shadows. However, the Android/iOS versions have even more effects and run just fine. With the custom font: On WP8, it'll just use Segoe UI Regular, which is the font that exists on the phone :)

Comment: I think then you can probably optimize further the use of the carousel. How are images being loaded into the Carousel? I would suggest to only load no more than 3 at a time. I believe there is a custom carousel component that does this on the forum or on Github. I take it you also used the new base theme for Touch 2.2 which strips out most of the CSS bulk and then built on top of that? And I suppose you have also compiled your app using the Sencha Command...try pasting this into your browsers console: 'document.getElementsByTagName("*").length' how many DOM items does it say? 1000 is too much.

Comment: I ended up talking with some folks at Sencha; they filed it as a bug for the framework, so I'll return with the fix when that bug is resolved. Thanks for the help!